# How to limit int values and str length in a re_path URL

Tags: python, django, regex, django-urls

I have a url that takes an `int` kwarg:

```
re_path(r'^posts/(?P<signature>\w+)/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', post_detail_view)
```

How do I:

- limit this so the `post_id` can only be 1 to 10 (inclusive)? Ie. not 0 or anything 11 and above.
- limit `signature` to be 128 chars or less?

Comment: Why not just do the validation for `signature` and  `post_id` values inside the function handling the request?

Comment: @Karl because I thought it's cleaner to return a 404 error than some messy response in a view

Comment: ... Can't you just set the response's status code to 404?

Comment: Yes, but that's not exactly DRY. An invalid URL format will deliver a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below Regex.

```
^posts\/(?P<signature>\w{1,128})\/(?P<post_id>[1-9]|10)\/$
```

The part {1,128} will limit your signature to 128 characters and [1-9]|10 will select just 1-9 and 10.

Comment: Fyi: In `re_path` you don't need to escape the `/`